# proc report: add indentation on sub-group

Tags: sas, report, display, proc-report

In proc report, I am having difficulty getting the indentation before second level (High Level Term 1) or third level and so on.

[image]

When I use style(column)=[cellwidth=6.5 cm JUST=LEFT asis=on], I get indentation but the continuous next line starts from the beginning because of the sentence length. Eg:

[image]

Is there a way to get indentation aligned for different level?

Here is my proc report program:

```
proc report data=final nowindows  split='~' headline headskip contents='' formchar(2)='_' missing spacing=1;
    *by seq seq_c1 seq_trt;
    columns  sqn seq ord cat _c1 - _c6;

    define sqn / group order=data noprint;
    define seq / group order=data noprint;
    define ord /display order=data noprint;

    define cat     / display  order=data style(column)=[cellwidth=6.5 cm JUST=LEFT asis=on]  style(header)=[JUST=LEFT] flow ;

    define _c1  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center] ;
    define _c2  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c3  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c4  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c5  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c6  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];

    compute cat;
        if ord=3 then  do; cat='   '||cat;  end;
        if ord=4 then do; cat='      '||cat;  end;
    endcomp;

    compute after sqn;
        line '';
    endcomp;

run;
```

Thank you.

Here is a small code to generate data:

```
data check;
length sqn 8. cat $100.;
input  sqn   cat $;
datalines;
1   Uncoded
2   Uncoded
3   ABNORMAL-MENSTRUATION-DIAGNOSTIC-CURETTAGE-OF-THE-UTERINE-CAVITY.
3   ANXIETY
3   CARPAL-TUNNEL-SYNDROME
3   EXACERBATION
 ;
run;
```

Comment: Please include the program as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Hi Joe, I have made updates with program. Thanks.

Comment: This is going to the PDF destination?  Or something else? And those two lines under `compute cat`, those are doing the indentation?

Comment: Also, could you show some example data (preferably in a `datalines` code block) that should replicate the issue?

Comment: I have added small data to generate two columns. This should be enough to get output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by using the actual style elements, rather than manually adding spaces.  Here `LEFTMARGIN` is probably the right way to go, although there is an `INDENT` style that sometimes is preferable; I think `LEFTMARGIN` gets you what you want.

You can see some questions on http://communities.sas.com, like [this one](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ods-pdf-proc-report-indent-column-conditionally/td-p/85624), with similar requests and answers (I used that question as a reference for this answer).

```
data check;
length sqn 8. cat $100 _c1-_c6 $16;
array _c[6] $ (6*"TestingText");
input  sqn   cat $;
seq=_n_;
ord = _n_;
datalines;
1   Uncoded
2   Uncoded
3   ABNORMAL-MENSTRUATION-DIAGNOSTIC-CURETTAGE-OF-THE-UTERINE-CAVITY.
3   ANXIETY
3   CARPAL-TUNNEL-SYNDROME
3   EXACERBATION
 ;
run;
ods pdf file="c:\temp\test.pdf";
proc report data=check nowindows  split='~' headline headskip contents='' formchar(2)='_' missing spacing=1;
    *by seq seq_c1 seq_trt;
    columns  sqn seq ord cat _c1 - _c6;

    define sqn / group order=data noprint;
    define seq / group order=data noprint;
    define ord /display order=data noprint;

    define cat     / display  order=data style(column)=[cellwidth=6.5 cm JUST=LEFT asis=on]  style(header)=[JUST=LEFT] flow ;

    define _c1  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center] ;
    define _c2  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c3  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c4  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c5  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];
    define _c6  / display order = data style(column)=[cellwidth=2.8 cm JUST=LEFT] style(header)=[JUST=Center];

    compute cat;
        if ord=3 then  call define('cat','style','style={leftmargin=0.1in}');
        if ord=4 then  call define('cat','style','style={leftmargin=0.2in}');      
    endcomp;

    compute after sqn;
        line '';
    endcomp;

run;
ods pdf close;
```